# Is it possible to run programs nodejs in bash?

Tags: bash, node.js, javascript

My question is simple : I have a program written in nodejs and want to run it in an infinite loop in the language `bash`, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

no problem

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    node <myapp>
done
```

you can also use it as a one liner
`while true; do; node <myapp>; done;`

Comment: My program is called main.js, to run it i  should do: while true; do; node <main.js>; done; ?

Comment: by convention when you specify something inside <> it must be replaced by the real name